# Is there a better way to change button display in javascript/Vue?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js

After writing so many if else, I feel very tired. I'm using Vue. The following code are written in the script section of the vue file. I get a json from file, and then read the values in json, then set what button should be display based on employee level and on application status. Is there a better way to change the button display status in Vue?

```
if (
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "1" &&
        (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Checking" ||
          this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Pending" ||
          this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Approved")) ||
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "2" &&
        (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Pending" ||
          this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Approved")) ||
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "3" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Approved")
    ) {
      this.pullDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.pullDisplay = false;
    };

    if (
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "1" &&
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Revising"
    ) {
      this.cancelDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.cancelDisplay = false;
    };

    if (
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "1" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Revising") ||
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "2" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Checking") ||
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "3" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Pending")
    ) {
      this.saveDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.saveDisplay = false;
    };

    if (
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "1" &&
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Revising"
    ) {
      this.reviseDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.reviseDisplay = false;
    };

    if (
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "2" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Checking") ||
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "3" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Pending")
    ) {
      this.sendDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.sendDisplay = false;
    };

    if (
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "3" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Pending") ||
      (this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "2" &&
        this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Checking")
    ) {
      this.approvalDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.approvalDisplay = false;
    };
```

And also there are a few ones need three conditions:

```
    if (
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "3" &&
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].requestCategory ==
        "External Request" &&
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus ==
        "Pending"
    ) {
      this.returnDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.returnDisplay = false;
    }
```

Comment: To simplify your code, I'd suggest using variables for each of these very long dotted structures. For instance, `let level = this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel` or `let checking = this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus == "Checking"`. Local variables will make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with a configuration based approach will make your code much more easy to edit and to read.

```
const levels = {
  '1': {
    pullDisplayStatus: ['Checking', 'Pending', 'Approved'],
    cancelDisplayStatus: ['Revising'],
    saveDisplayStatus: ['Revising'],
    reviseDisplayStatus: ['Revising'],
    sendDisplayStatus: [],
    approvalDisplayStatus: [],
  },
  '2': {
    pullDisplayStatus: ['Pending', 'Approved'],
    cancelDisplayStatus: [],
    saveDisplayStatus: ['Checking'],
    reviseDisplayStatus: [],
    sendDisplayStatus: ['Checking'],
    approvalDisplayStatus: ['Checking'],
  },
  '3': {
    pullDisplayStatus: ['Approved'],
    cancelDisplayStatus: [],
    saveDisplayStatus: ['Pending'],
    reviseDisplayStatus: [],
    sendDisplayStatus: ['Pending'],
    approvalDisplayStatus: ['Pending'],
  },
}

const jsonForGlobal = this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal;
const currentStatus = jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus;
const level = levels[jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel];
this.pullDisplay = level.pullDisplayStatus.indexOf(currentStatus) > -1;
this.cancelDisplay = level.cancelDisplayStatus.indexOf(currentStatus) > -1;
this.saveDisplay = level.cancelDisplayStatus.indexOf(currentStatus) > -1;
this.reviseDisplay = level.reviseDisplayStatus.indexOf(currentStatus) > -1;
this.sendDisplay = level.reviseDisplayStatus.indexOf(currentStatus) > -1;
```

Comment: Btw I just found another one that need three conditions. What to do for this? ```    if (
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.employeeLevel == "3" &&
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].requestCategory ==
        "External Request" &&
      this.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].currentStatus ==
        "Pending"
    ) {
      this.returnDisplay = true;
    } else {
      this.returnDisplay = false;
    }```

Comment: you could add a returnDisplayStatus array and if the requestCategory is a one of usage then just do: `this.returnDisplay = level.returnDisplayStatus.indexOf(currentStatus) > -1 && jsonForGlobal.detail[this.detailId].requestCategory == 'External Request';`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a property often it makes sense to introduce a local variable for it to clean things up:

```
 const { employeeLevel, detail: { [this.detailId]: { currentStatus }}} = his.GLOBAL2.jsonForGlobal;
```

Secondly you don't need the `if` / `else`, you can just assign the boolean:

```
  this.pullDisplay = (
     employeeLevel == "1" && ["Checking", "Pending", "Approved"].includes(currentStatus) || 
     employeeLevel == "2" && ["Pending", "Approved"].includes(currentStatus) ||
     employeeLevel == "3" && currentStatus == "Approved"
)
```